# How to get list of cells that match criteria in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, cross-reference

I have three columns in an Excel 2013 spreadsheet. One is an ID, one is a reference column, and one is a referenced by column. Some rows reference other rows, and some rows are referenced by other rows. The references could be a one-to-many relationship (many secondary rows reference one important row). Is there away to fill a cell with a list of cells that reference another cell?

```
| ID   |  REF | REF-BY |
------------------------
| 001  |      |002,003 |
------------------------
| 002  | 001  |        |
------------------------
| 003  | 001  |        |
------------------------
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried Excel 2013's Inquire feature? http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/558-tips-improving-excel-workbook-inquire-tool  http://www.accountingweb.co.uk/article/excel-2013-inquire-add/535095

Comment: Just so we’re clear: are you asking how to generate Column `C` from Columns `A` and `B`?

Comment: yes, I want to put the contents of a2 and a3 into c1

Comment: Inquire solves the problem, but if possible, I'd like to do it through a formula, rather than having the user click on a button. I don't want them to need to enable Inquire unless necessary.

Comment: can you put a macro in the workbook?

Comment: yes, but I haven't used Excel macros, so I'm not sure what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go around this is to include a custom function in Excel to calculate the result for you. Include the following code in a new module in VBA. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the Visual Basic Editor, and then click Insert --> Module. Paste the following code ind the new module and close the Visual Basic Editor again.

```
Function MatchCriteria(ID As Range, REF As Range) As String
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Str As String
    For Each Cell In REF
        If Cell.Value = ID.Value And Cell.Row <> ID.Row Then
            If Str = vbNullString Then
                Str = Cells(Cell.Row, ID.Column).Value
            Else
                Str = Str & ", " & Cells(Cell.Row, ID.Column).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
    MatchCriteria = Str
End Function
```

You can now use this function as seen in the following picture.

[image]

The first input in the function defines the ID and the second input defines your "referenced by column". Note that in my version of excel (danish) the input delimiter is "`;`. If you are using an english version of Excel you should be using a comma, `,`.